# Laravel 8 pagination returns blank page

Tags: php, laravel

Pagination is returning blank on next page. The result gets found but lost when I go to next page. This is query in my controller

```
if($request->has('SearchBtn')){
 $search = $request->input('Search');
$query = \App\User::join('suppliers', 'users.id' ,'=', 'suppliers.user_id')
->where('company', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
->paginate(1);
  
  if($query->isEmpty()){
    $query = \App\Keywords::join('users', 'users.id' ,'=', 'keywords.user_id')
    ->join('suppliers', 'users.id' ,'=', 'suppliers.user_id')
    ->where('Keyword', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->paginate(1);
  }
  
  return view('/Buyers/SearchResult', compact('query'));
}
```

And this is `dd($query)`

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#1238 ▼
#total: 2
#lastPage: 2
#items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1233 ▶}
#perPage: 1
#currentPage: 1
#path: "http://localhost:8000/Buyers/SearchResult"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
+onEachSide: 3
#options: array:2 [▶]
}
```

As you can see it finds pages but can show only first one. My guess is that it has something to do with `join` because queries without it work just fine with `paginate()`. I honestly don't know what to try or how to start debugging this. If I switch `paginate()` with `get()` everything is fine and the data is shown correctly.

This is `dd($request)`

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#43 ▼
 #json: null
 #convertedFiles: []
 #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#246 ▶}
 #routeResolver: Closure() {#255 ▶}
 +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
 +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51 ▶}
 +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51 ▶}
 +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#47 ▶}
 +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48 ▶}
 +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#46 ▶}
 +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49 ▶}
 #content: null
 #languages: null
 #charsets: null
 #encodings: null
 #acceptableContentTypes: null
 #pathInfo: "/Buyers/SearchResult"
 #requestUri: "/Buyers/SearchResult?_token=RG7LzXrHaL4x2jHOoCHC3TLbUqs22XaJDjuulOCo&Search=company&SearchBtn="
 #baseUrl: ""
 #basePath: null
 #method: "GET"
 #format: null
 #session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#269 ▶}
 #locale: null
 #defaultLocale: "en"
 -preferredFormat: null
 -isHostValid: true
 -isForwardedValid: true
 -isSafeContentPreferred: null
 basePath: ""
 format: "html"
}
```

**UPDATE 1.0**:
The blank page was returned due to this statement `if($request->has('SearchBtn'))`  however now I face a new problem when I search something I get correct number of pages and when I got to the next page page count goes up and it shows all the results from the database.

**UPDATE 1.1**
And I fixed that by appending search to the query like this

```
$query = \App\User::join('suppliers', 'users.id' ,'=', 'suppliers.user_id')
->where('company', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
->paginate(1)->appends(['Search'=>$search]);
```

Comment: have you tried using a leftjoin and not just join.

Comment: same thing happens, pages are shown but blank page is returned

Comment: dd the first query on the second page . dd also the request body

Comment: i edited the question with request while query returns ```null```

Comment: remember pagination expect page number in the query parameters. That's why i was asking for you to dd request body